# Set time limit for items in container in CosmosDB using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure (bot framework v4)

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

I want to set the time to live for the items in a container in cosmosDB, but I am not sure how to do so using the config of cosmosdb storage in bot framework v4. I would appreciate some help on this matter.

I have read about setting time to live using DocumentClient() as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-time-to-live#enable-time-to-live-on-a-container-using-sdk). However I set up my storage like this:

```
var storage = new CosmosDbStorage(new CosmosDbStorageOptions
        {
            AuthKey = CosmosDBKey,
            CollectionId = CosmosDBCollectionName,
            CosmosDBEndpoint = new Uri(CosmosServiceEndpoint),
            DatabaseId = CosmosDBDatabaseName,
        });
```

How can I set time to live with this config of my cosmosDB storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BotBuilder SDK doesn't currently allow you to create a Collection with `DefaultTimeToLive`.

However, you can do so in the Azure Portal once your Collection has been created and then set it:

1. Open the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com)
2. Go to your Resource Group
3. Open your CosmosDB Service
4. On the left, go to Data Explorer
5. Expand your Database
6. Expand your Collection
7. Click Scale & Settings
8. Adjust Settings > Time to Live

   [image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this will be allowed in BotBilder SDK in the future - is it on the road map? If so, when?

Comment: To my knowledge, this specific item isn't on the roadmap. However, there is a newer Cosmos SDK that was released recently. When we update to that, I'm fairly confident that this will be included. No ETA on this currently as at some point, the new Cosmos SDK didn't work with non-partitioned databases--I'm not sure if that still holds true.